# How to find all empty files recursively

Tags: c#, powershell

How would you find all empty files in a directory that are empty. A given file may have carriage returns or blank spaces. i need to capture those as well. I can can use code in either powershell or c#.

Comment: Well, start with (posting) the code to search recursively. Then consider how the results can be filtered ...

Comment: Just enumerate all the files in a directory (possibly recursivly), then just use `System.IO.FileInfo` on each one and check the length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The System.IO have the classes you want

```
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\Luke101");
    FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles();

    foreach (FileInfo fi in fiArr)
    {
        if(fi.Length == 0)
        {
            //.. Then do stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: @pst the op's question say's  "empty files in a directory that are empty" so recursive is not required by op

Comment: Usual case of mismatched title I suppose .. also "A given file may have carriage returns or blank spaces." though.

Answer (score 3):

Powershell makes it easy:

`Get-ChildItem -Path C:\dir -recurse -Filter { $_.Length -eq 0 }`

`#YOUR HOMEWORK: filter for your CRLF criteria as well`

Comment: The -File flag should be added as the question asks for empty files.

Answer (score 2):

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo("Your path").GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach(var file in files) 
{
    using(var r = new StreamReader(file.OpenRead()))
    {
       string content = r.ReadToEnd();
       if(string.IsnullOrWhitespace(content))
       {
       // do stuff
       }
    }
}
```

Code is off the top of my had, didn't test it, by you can get the idea.

Comment: Downvoted because the `StreamReader` you're creating and opening is bit scary. It will not only load the entire contents of the file into memory before checking the length (unwieldy at best, dangerous at worst), but it is never explicitly disposed, meaning that the place/time of releasing resources is indeterminate. Translation: The open file would turn into a memory leak pretty easily...

Comment: Edited, thanks. I just tend to spit out one-liners because stakoverflow's post editor is terrible when it comes to indentation (I want my TAB working, dammit!).

Comment: And to be completely cool, it would be better to read file line-by-line and stop when a non-space symbol is there. It would be more productive. But op's request more looks like a homework, so I don't really care.

Answer (score 0):

Get all zero byte length files or files that has only spaces, tabs, CR from the beginning of the file to the end.

```
Get-ChildItem <path> -Recurse | 
Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.Length -eq 0 -or ([IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName) -match '^\s+$') }
```